# Replace image with canvas image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

this is the first time I am using canvas and I am using it to grab images from the HTML document and put them into canvas so I can add effects to them with Javascript. The code I have works but creates a duplicate. I want to replace the original image with the new canvas image but anything I've tried makes either the canvas or all the images disappear from the page entirely. Any advice would be great! Someone also suggested to me placing the canvas image over top of the original but I can't seem to get there either...

Here is the code I have that creates the canvas:

```
var img = this[0]; // grab the first one, shake the jquery
var imgWidth = this.width();
var imgHeight = this.height();

var canvas = $("<canvas>");

// set the acutal w and h
canvas[0].width = imgWidth;
canvas[0].height = imgHeight;

var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

// dump the image into the canvas
console.log(ctx);
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
var data = pixels.data;
```

Comment: It would help if you offered a little more context. Is this inside of a function? Where did `this[0]` come from? Odds are you want [jQuery `remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<canvas>` HTML node can be used in place of an `<img>` for most intends and purposes. But when you want a HTML `<img>` node to show the content of a canvas, there is a way to do this.

1. Convert the current content of the canvas to a data-url with `var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();`
2. assign the data-url to the src-attribute of your image with `image.src = dataURL;`

Answer (score 0):

if `this[0]` is your image element, then use:

```
$(this[0]).parent().html(canvas[0])
```